# COUNTIF formula counts values that don't match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I'm using counting invoice numbers (text) in a table's column, but the Excel formula seems to be confusing some values.

I copied small sample of these - please refer to below:

[image: Sample range]

The formulas are as follow:

> =COUNTIFS(A1:A19,A1)
>
> =COUNTIF(A1:A19,A1)

As you can see these invoice numbers differ and the results of these functions suggest as if all were the same.

I googled it for 1 hour but I didn't find such as issue as mine.

If anybody had any clue why could this behave in such way I'll be super grateful!

Rob

Comment: You need to make the range absolute: `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$19,A1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this myself:

**ROOTCAUSE**

1. Excel tried to be helpful and read these invoice numbers as actual numbers (despite these being defined already in Power Query as text)
2. Then, Excel fooled me and despite showing that it works on it as a string (I was evaluating the formula) it worked on it as number
3. Above means that it transformed exemplary "00100001010000018525" to 1.00001E+17, which cut down this to "100001010000018000" - that's the moment Excel stopped fooling around and showed that value in the formula bar.

I think I don't need to tell why countif perceived all these values as equal.

**SOLUTION**

I simply appended one letter after each invoice number to get e.g. "00100001010000018525a" what forces Excel to quit its gimmicks and games.

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you copy down this formula it will add 1 row to each. For example the second row of datas formula will be `=COUNTIFS(A2:A20,A2)`. To lock these cells in the formula use `$`
Your formula should be `=COUNTIFS(A$1:A$19,A1)`

Comment: Hi, I know about locking the references and that isn't my point really (I just needed it in my tool as a running range since my invoices are sorted). My point is about countif formula showing higher result than valid (finding match in these invoice numbers despite them being different).

Comment: Yeah I understand why that is happening and it is down to the fact that the reference for the range part of the formula isnt locked. Therefore eachtime you are asking it to count its counting one less as the row above is no longer in the formula

Comment: Hey guys, please - can you forget about the reference locking for a second? If you could pay attention to the values in column "A" - notice they are different. Then take a look at cell "B1" (or "C1" as a matter of fact) - do you see that countif formula recognizes the all values as the same? E.g. in cell "B1" the result should be 2, but it is 19 - this is my real issue here...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a bug in `COUNTIF`, or maybe by design.
However, to workaround this in the formula, without having to change your data, try adding a wild-card character:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A19,"*"&A1)
```

Comment: Thanks Ron, your approach is even better alternative to solution I proposed as it doesn't engage creation of additional column. I tested it and it works just fine, probably forcing Excel into treating each value as text string rather than number.